# WIX Paraffin inside Program files directory

Tags: wix, windows-installer, paraffin

I am new to WIX and I am trying to create a component from within the Program Files directory in Windows. In the Command line I cd to **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies** then I run the command 
`paraffin -dir ./ -custom GlobalSoftware globalsoftware.wxs -g`.
 Here i get a System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies' is denied. i get the same exception when I am logged in as an administrator.

How can I get around this problem?

Thank You, 
Venkat Rao

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just had to run the command line as administrator.

Answer (score 4):

[Paraffin](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2008/12/22/paraffin-3-0-now-with-full-wix-3-0-support.aspx) is not a part of WiX, it's written by John Robbins and you should contact him for support or look through the available source code.

As far as getting around it, I'd think that if you are trying to harvest the dependency of your project you could just set CopyLocal=true and then find the dll in the same output directory as your dll and try harvesting it from there.